# PHP lines with XML cause unexpected '>' errors

Tags: php, xml, character

When I set variables that include angle brackets  (< >) or slashes I keep getting errors like the following (code simplified to focus on error):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in D:\hosting\8499439\html\test.php on line 2

<?php
   $xml = “<Request>\n”;
?>
```

I also run into a lot off issues with "`unexpected T_String`" errors that appear to be related.

I'm running PHP5 on a GoDaddy Windows Server.

What am I doing wrong? (I get the impression I need to to do something so that special characters can be handled in my PHP).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're using curly quotes instead of regular ones!

Comment: What are you using to edit your php files? A standard text editor would NOT be inserting the curly quotes. `“` and `”` are NOT treated as `"` by PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes are curly quotes, not straight quotes, so PHP runs into an error processing them. A string can only be recognized with straight quotes.

Use the following code:

```
<?php
   $xml = "<Request>\n";
?>
```

Assuming that you have the same error elsewhere, you can probably do a simple search-and-replace to fix the error: search for one of the curly quotes, replace with a straight quote. Repeat with the other curly quote. Make sure to check for straight quotes that may need to be escaped (for instance, something like `"Mary said, "I like this.""` would need to be escaped as `"Mary said, \"I like this.\""`)

Comment: Thanks- very eagle eyes. You nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

mc10 is right. 
Additionally I can say, there are only ""(double) and ''(single) quotes in PHP. I suggest you to read about differences between them.
I prefer using single quotes only to keep code clear.